# R mvpart - splitting index

Tags: r, references, cart

I need to understand what `mvpart` is doing. Which index does it use as a splitting criterion (in my case, method=class)? Does it use simultaneous partitioning along multiple axis (multivariate)? Are there any references I can read on the subject?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16419238/splitting-rules-in-mvpart-vs-rpart

Comment: At present, this question is only about how an R function works. Thus, it is off-topic for CV (see our [help page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help)). Can you edit this Q to make it on-topic (eg, what are different splitting criteria, & their pros & cons). If not, this Q may need to be closed. (If the answer below is not enough to address your needs, you could also try the [r-help-listserv](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-help).)

Comment: @gung   You may close this question....I will turn to r-list

Comment: Did you not get the information you needed from Gavin's answer below? Since the question is already here, there's no reason not to get what you can. (The question will be closed as off-topic, but it will not be deleted.)

Answer (score 2):

If you are fitting a multivariate regression tree (MRT), then you need `method = "mrt"` - i.e. if you are using a matrix for the response, you can't use `method = "class"`. If you just have a vector response, then if this is a factor and you use `method = "class"`, then `mvpart` is doing nothing different to `rpart` i.e. the *usual* thing for a classification tree.

If you have a matrix response, you can't fit a classification tree.

However, you can view the MRT as a constrained (supervised) clustering tool as it forms groups of samples (clusters) that best explain variance in the response matrix.

If you use `method = "mrt"` then `mvpart` uses a sums of squares criterion to evaluate splits. If you use `method = "class"` **and** have a univariate response then by default `mvpart` (calling `rpart`) will choose splits that minimise the Gini criterion. You can change the split criterion in this instance, via argument `params`, but you'll need to read the documentation for **rpart** (the package) to find out what other criteria are allowed and how to specify them.

Comment: @ Gavin I am using a vector response. If in my case mvpart is doing the same thing as rpart, then why do I get different trees when I run one and the other ? The first split is the same, but the following ones are not.

Comment: @Clementina You have the code, go look. Less facetiously, I don't know how closely mvpart tracks rpart, but it was at one point in time *the same code* - you can look at the code to see that it is calling modified rpart functions, but as far as I was aware, the modifications were only due to the addition of the `class = "mrt"` bit. You should also check that settings in `rpart.control` are the same in both functions. If you only have a univariate response, don't load **mvpart**, just load **rpart** & then you don't need to worry. Why do you want to use a multivariate tool for a univariate `y`?

Comment: @ Gavin  Because mvpart has a more flexible, nicer-looking output. Thank you for your comments and suggestions....

Comment: @Clementina Then take a look at the **party** package or in the **plotmo** packages for much better plotting. The latter works with **rpart** trees.